# Filter data from XSLT

Tags: xslt, if-statement

I have a XSL file in which I am creating a field like this:

```
<ServiceText>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Yrs,'-',Mos,'-',Days,'-',Hrs)" />
</ServiceText>
```

The values of 'Yrs,'-',Mos,'-',Days,'-',Hrs , I am receiving from a Web service response and assiging it to the XSL directly. I cannot do any modification to the data in code for these fields, because that is how the ocde is. All data manipulation is on the xslt.

I want to do a data filtering on xslt as follows:

```
if value of yrs =-1 then yrs=""
if value of mos =-1 then mos=""
if value of Days =-1 then Days=""
if value of Hrs =-1 then Hrs=""
```

How can I do it on the XSL file?

Comment: Do you still want to output the hypens if any of the values are -1?

Comment: Yes I want the '-' if values are -1. I am using xslt 1.0. The 2 answers below does not work for me.

Comment: Can this be done by a simple implementation like <xsl:if test="DLStateCd!='' and DLStateDesc!='' ">
                              <ServiceText>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Yrs,'-',Mos,'-',Days,'-',Hrs)" />
</ServiceText>
                            </xsl:if>

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <ServiceText>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join((Yrs, Mos, Days, Hrs)[.!=-1],'-')" />
    </ServiceText>
</xsl:template>
```

See link for a [Working example](http://xsltransform.net/bFukv88)

Answer (score 0):

**In XSLT 1.0 use something like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*/*[not(.= -1)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., substring('-', 2 - not(self::Hrs)))"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*/*[. = -1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <Yrs>-1</Yrs>
 <Mos>7</Mos>
 <Days>15</Days>
 <Hrs>3</Hrs>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
7-15-3
```

**Do Note**:

It seems that there is an assumption that the "-1" values form a contiguous group (right to left in the sequence Yrs, Mos,Days).

**If this assumption is violated, it would be impossible to understand what is the missing part** in `2013-10-8` -- is it the months or the days ?